# Hub-Spoke model with Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I'm trying to create **Hub-Spoke** topology with Cassandra. I want to have one centralised C* server and many spoke c* servers. Whenever a new records comes to any of the spoke, it should be moved to Hub c* server. I tried with replication startegies but its seems to be bi-directional. Means, If i insert a record in node1 and i'm able to see the record in all the nodes in my cluster.any suggestions/guidance will highly appreciated here.

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature introduced in DataStax Enterprise 5.0. You can find all the details in the [docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/advRep/advRepTOC.html), but super summarized the DSE Advanced Replication provides a unidirectional replication from remote clusters to a central hubs which also supports prioritization of data streams.

Comment: Thank you for your info.I'm looking same with cassandra or any other ways to manage to build such topology hub-spoke with cassandra itself.

Comment: @BDR Cassandra itself does not have this feature.  You would need to implement it yourself, or use DataStax Enterprise which includes this feature (among many others) built on top of Cassandra.

Comment: @Zanson it will be helpful if you could provide me any  blogs or examples which talks abt Hub-Spoke with cassadnra to build it by myself.

Comment: @BDR I don't know of any, you have to figure it out on your own, or use DSE.

Comment: Sure @Zanson Thank you very much for your time.